# Sublime Settings — Syntax Specific: "show_panel_on_build" not overriding with Markdown syntax

Tags: macos, sublime-text-2, markdown

I am trying to turn off the build panel showing on build when using markdown syntax. I am on OSX and using Marked for markdown preview and I don't want the build panel popping up with a pointless "build finished" message. I have put the following in my markdown syntax specific and multimarkdown syntax specific preferences:

`{
    "show_panel_on_build": false
}`

But it does not work. I have tested the syntax specific preference file with other settings and they have worked, but this setting does not.

I was also able to change the same "show_panel_on_build" setting in my default settings and it worked, but I want only markdown to not show build results. Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using [Markdown Preview](https://sublime.wbond.net/packages/Markdown%20Preview)? This package's default settings contain an override for `show_panel_on_build`. You can override this yourself by modifying your Markdown Preview user settings.

You can find these settings in Preferences » Package Settings » Markdown Preview » Settings, or:

- default settings: `Packages/Markdown Preview/MarkdownPreview.sublime-settings`
- user settings: `Packages/User/MarkdownPreview.sublime-settings`